# for loop break after using gregexpr

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm going back to R after a few months without practicing and I am kind of dumbfounded from what happens there

```
for (year in c('09', '08', '10', '11',
          '12', '13', '14', '15')){

  col <- paste("price_", year, sep="")
  print(col)

  mpt <- gregexpr("P\\.T.*(\\d|,|\\.)+", data[col], perl=TRUE)
  print('done')
  pt_matches = regmatches(data[col], mpt)
  print("matches")}
```

It seems fairly easy and I expected to have this output:

```
"price_09"
"done"
"matches"
"price_08"
... # and so on
```

However, R does not seem to execute even a full loop, I get only:

```
"price_09"
"done"
```

And nothing else. I don't get an error message, as if assigning `mpt` acted as a 'break'. Do I miss something obvious ?

If I delete the `mpt`assignment I get the print "matches" printed but it obviously crashes further down the road

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?gregexpr`, the `text` argument

```
gregexpr(pattern, text, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

takes a `vector`

> text - a character vector where matches are sought, or an object which
>   can be coerced by as.character to a character vector. Long vectors are
>   supported.

Here, the `data[col]` is still a `data.frame`.  In order to convert it to `vector`, use the `[[`

Using a reproducible example,

```
d1 <- data.frame(v1 = c('pine', 'tree', 'chill'))
regmatches(d1['v1'], gregexpr('pi', d1['v1']))
#$v1
#character(0)

regmatches(d1[['v1']], gregexpr('pi', d1[['v1']]))
#[[1]]
#[1] "pi"

#[[2]]
#character(0)

#[[3]]
#character(0)
```

Comment: Seems to work... I don't understand why I didn't get an error message though. Thanks !